# image source not readable

Tags: php, laravel

I want to upload an image from external source but I get an error that image source not readable, I really do not know whether the URL for the image is incomplete or it is another issue
here is my code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProfilesController extends Controller
{
public function index(\App\Models\User $user)
 {
    // if (!isset($user)){
    //     return abort(404);
    // }else{
    //     $user = User::find($user);
    //     return view('profiles.index',[
    //         'user'=> $user,
    //     ]);
    // }
    return view('profiles.index',compact('user'));
}

public function edit(\App\Models\User $user)
{
    $this->authorize('update',$user->profile);
    return view('profiles.edit',compact('user'));
}
public function update(User $user){
    $this->authorize('update',$user->profile);
    $data = request()->validate([
        'title'=>'required',
        'description'=>'required',
        'url'=>'url',
        'image'=>'',
    ]);
    if(request('image')){
        $imagePath = (request('image')->store('profile','public'));
        $image = Image::make(public_path("storage/{$imagePath}"))->fit(100,100);
        $image->save();

        auth()->user()->profile->update(array_merge(
            $data,
            ['image'=>$imagePath]
        ));
       
     } 
    
      return redirect("/profile/{$user->id}");
     }
    }
```

any help guys?, i will really appreciate
below is the error

Intervention\Image\Exception\NotReadableException
Image source not readable

Comment: Can you please, also provide an example of request please? cUrl should be ok

Comment: What did you mean that the image source is not readable? Can you show the error msg?

Comment: the error is Intervention\Image\Exception\NotReadableException

Comment: Image source not readable

Comment: Have you run `php artisan storage:link`?

Comment: yeah i ran it in cmd and were like The [C:\xampp\htdocs\app\public\storage] link already exists.

Answer (score 0):

use Image;

```
$destinationPath = public_path('storage/{$imagePath}');
$img = Image::make($image->path());
$img->resize(100, 100, function ($constraint) {
    $constraint->aspectRatio();
})->save($destinationPath.'/'.$input['imagename']);
```

Comment: Thanks, but i dont have variables $image and $input

Comment: You can change it in order to your real situation